# UserControl with changing content template for displaying content

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a situation in which i need to create a user control that hosts a content presenter. Now, the content presenter should be using the template to display data.

I have designed a user control as follows. xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="Dashboard.ComponentStatisticsControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         Name="SatisticsControl"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=SatisticsControl, Path=Title}" 
           Grid.Row="0"
           Background="SkyBlue"/>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding ElementName=SatisticsControl, Path=AdditionalContent}"
                      Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now i have a WrapPanel defined in my MainWindow.xaml that should host the ComponentStatisticsControl

```
<Window x:Class="Dashboard.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Dashboard"
    Height="350" Width="525"
    ShowInTaskbar="True"
    WindowState="Maximized"
    WindowStyle="None"
    Name="_this">
    <Window.Resources>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="PanelBackground" 
                         StartPoint="0, 1"
                         EndPoint="1, 0">
            <GradientStop Color="SkyBlue" Offset="0.3"/>
            <GradientStop Color="PaleGreen" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="BorderBrush"
                     Color="Blue"/>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0">
            <Button Click="Button_Click"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">Click</Button>
        </StackPanel>
        <WrapPanel Name="WrapPanelMain"
               Orientation="Horizontal"
               FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
               Grid.Row="1">
        </WrapPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Now i am creating the content for the ComponentStatisticsControl in code behind.

```
    public void CreateComponent(ref DiscoveryMessage Message)
    {
        switch (Message.Identifier)
        {
            case ComponentIdentifier.Dispatcher:
                {
                    ComponentStatisticsControl StatisticsControl = new ComponentStatisticsControl();
                    StatisticsControl.Title = "Dispatcher";
                    StatisticsControl.AdditionalContent = new Label() { Content = "Hello"};
                    WrapPanelMain.Children.Add(StatisticsControl);
                    break;   
                }
        }
    }
```

However, i can not see the data added. What did i miss out. I have spent much time banging about what went wrong.

I should be able to see the content set for the label "Hello" in the WrapPanel.

```
public class DispatcherStatistics
{
    private uint f_QCount;

    public uint QueueCount { get { return f_QCount; } 
        set 
        { 
            f_QCount = value;
        } 
    }

}
```

I will be setting this class instance to the AdditionalContent. So that QueueCount will be updated whenever i assign a new instance of this class.

Thanks in advance

EDIT
I was getting the text of my class type in the wrap panel. Now the above problem is solved, but how can i define a template for the content to show.

```
    public void CreateComponent(ref DiscoveryMessage Message)
    {
        1switch (Message.Identifier)
        {
            case ComponentIdentifier.Dispatcher:
                {
                    ComponentStatisticsControl StatisticsControl = new ComponentStatisticsControl();
                    StatisticsControl.Title = "Dispatcher";
                    StatisticsControl.AdditionalContent = f_clDispatcherStatistics;
                    WrapPanelMain.Children.Add(StatisticsControl);
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
```

f_clDispatcherStatistics is a private instance variable for DispatcherStatistics class
This is displaying "Dashboard.DispatcherStatistics"

I want to display something like

QueueCount : 0

like this format.

Comment: Content="{Binding ElementName=SatisticsControl <-- is this correctly spelled? can this be the error?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it a little complicated. You can use the `Content` property of `UserControl` directly.

Here is the important part of the template (using the default `ContentPresenter`):

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=SatisticsControl, Path=Title}" 
       Grid.Row="0"
       Background="SkyBlue"/>
    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

And then use the `Content` property directly:

```
ComponentStatisticsControl StatisticsControl = new ComponentStatisticsControl();
StatisticsControl.Title = "Dispatcher";
StatisticsControl.Content = new Label() { Content = "Hello"};
WrapPanelMain.Children.Add(StatisticsControl);
```

Comment: I corrected my UserControl with the one u suggested. Please see my edit above. Thanks

Comment: I can't follow anymore. If the initial problem is solved, good. If you have a new one, create a new question.

Comment: @melike Setting the content is showing only the label. I think that AdditionalContent which i have declared should exist. As the UserControl's content property is showing only the label

Comment: It does not make senso to have an `AdditionalContent` if you do not even use the `Content`. If you need more than one element, wrap it in a container or use multiple controls. If you have many labels, use string properties and bind to them in the template.